# Url routing in mvc 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, routes

I want to have below specific Url routing for my website

http://www.MyWebsite?Region=US&Area=South

based on passed Region and Area query string parameter, i want to redirect to a specific controller action.

Problems:

1. What should be the Url Routing ?
2. Whether creating a common controller action which redirects to specific action will work here?

Any help would be greatly appriciated !!

Thanks

Comment: In MVC we pass the Controller/Action, to generate the view. If you don`t specify that, it has a default route that is Homt/Index. Now in Index ActionMethod you may capture the querystrings like this: Index(string region, string area). MVC will automatically send the arguments to this variable based on the url.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do querystring right off the root, then you need to map routes in global this way.  Inside your action you can access context and grab querystring from it.  Below is my example to do twitter style usernames, but idea is the same.

```
routes.MapRoute("UserSettings",
          "{username}/settings",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Settings", username = "" },
          new { username = new NotNullOrEmptyConstraint() }
        );
```

public class NotNullOrEmptyConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {

```
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        try
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(values["username"].ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


 public ActionResult Settings(string username){
 }
```